# Create names for a vector of arbitrary length in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a function that names vectors (or rows of a matrix) of arbitrary (but known) length with two categories of variables located at arbitrary (but known) locations.

For example, if my vector is

```
vec <- 1:8
```

and I want to name the entries 1,3,5,7 as A1,A2,A3,A4 and the entries 2,4,6,8 as B1,B2,B3,B4 by providing

```
indexA <- c(1,3,5,7)
indexB <- c(2,4,6,8)
```

Since I input vectors of variable length and variable locations (both known), I need to do this automatically. The next vector might be `1:123` with a different location of the categories A and B.

Comment: Try with `paste0("A", seq_along(indexA))` and `paste0("B", seq_along(indexB))`

Comment: @akrun If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. A hint about how to assign those names to the corresponding rows of a matrix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `seq_along` to get the sequence of the `vector` and `paste` with letters `"A"`, `"B"` to give the names attribute to the vector

```
names(indexA) <- paste0("A", seq_along(indexA))
indexA     
# A1 A2 A3 A4 
# 1  3  5  7
```

Similarly, this can be done with 'indexB'